# Modifying the search result of grep

Tags: shell, grep, pdf, file-metadata

Normally, we can search a `keyword` in a list of pdf files using the following command:

```
for file in *pdf; do 
pdftotext "$file" - | grep keyword
done
```

Now, from the search result, If I want to find the title name along with the authors/writers of the file manually, without using `pdfinfo` command, what will I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

When you convert a PDF file with `pdftotext` the meta information gets lost. But, `pdftotext` has an option which is interesting:

```
-htmlmeta
       Generate a simple HTML file, including the meta information.  This simply wraps the 
       text in <pre> and </pre> and  prepends the meta headers.
```

Now, you can grep for the metainfo too:

```
pdftotext -htmlmeta file.pdf - | \
  grep -oP '.*keyword.*|<title>\K.*(?=</title>)|<meta name="Author" content="\K.*(?="/>)'
```

This will search for `keyword` in the PDF file. Then separated by `|` other 2 search patterns will be extracted from the document: the title and the author of the document. The result looks like this:

```
title of the document
author of the document
search pattern
```

Or use `perl`, which can format the text after a match, unlike `grep`:

```
pdftotext -htmlmeta file.pdf - | perl -ne '/keyword/ && print "Pattern: $_"; /<title>(.*)<\/title>/ && print "Title: $1\n"; /<meta name="Author" content="([^"]+)/ && print "Author: $1\n"'
```

The output looks then:

```
Title: title of the document
Author: author of the document
Pattern: bla bla search pattern bla bla
```